# Code review tools for Java development with Eclipse + SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, subversion, code-review

Astonishingly, I recently found my new team has no code review process at all.

I am used to Visual Studio and new to JAVA development. So I'd like to ask about good free code review tools for Java development with Eclipse + SVN.

I have found some. I don't list them here since I don't want to make my post like an AD. Really appreciate your field experiences.

Comment: You should probably edit your post to list the ones you're not interested in.

Comment: Could you tell us more about what you are looking for? What features should the software have? Are there concrete elements that you are used from Visual Studio that you like very much and are looking for?

Comment: Along the names of the ones you've already looked at, please point out why you think they are not fit. If you didn't take a closer look and just don't know which of them *might* fit, you should at least include your requirements with your question. See: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used [Code Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/product/collaborator/overview/) which I found was a good tool for doing code reviews.  I know it integrates with SVN not sure about Eclipse directly.

I used Code Collaborator at a former employer where our version control system was Accurev.  From my reading of the documentation it sound like the tool might have a better integration with SVN.

When doing Agile development sprints my teams flow for code review was we would check code into our Team Level in Accurev and someone once a day would enter all the accurev transaction ids into the Code Collaborator Gui to create a review of usually all the code that was checked in the day before.  Then everyone would use the tool to leave comments ask questions etc.  Generally anything that actually needed to be fixed would be reviewed in the next review.

When doing Bug fixes generally it was similar accept the Team area was more locked down so that transaction ids were from files that were kept(Accurev has an idea of saving files in like your own personal area).

Before we had this tool emailing around files and diffs was the only way code was reviewed so having a tool that allowed seeing the diffs and chatting about the particular lines of code was a lot nicer.

Comment: Could you tell us more about this tool? What are its features and flaws? How did your workflow with it look like? Any tricky situations that needed additional attention?